# insert content into Template through Variable

Tags: php

I want to use my index.php page as my template for all my other pages. So I'm printing it out with the code below.

```
echo file_get_contents("index.php");
```

I've added this piece of code into the template (index.php) where i want to display the contents. of whichever page im on.

```
<?php
echo $index_content;
?>
```

So when I use

```
echo file_get_contents("index.php");
```

to get my page template, on for example users.php. In the users.php file I want to use the code below

```
$index_content = echo "string";
```

to then print out my page contents where I added this variable

```
<?php
echo $index_content;
?>
```

My problem is when I say $index_contents = echo ("string");

it's not printing anything out. onto my template. or it prints the stuff out but at the end or the beginning of the template. not where i've inserted my variable. Why wont it echo out my stuff where I've inserted my variable.

Comment: Do you want to do something like `$test= echo "Test":
echo $test;`?

Comment: yes. If i can get my code to at least echo out a string i can figure out the rest

Comment: The problem is that on load. my page is not printing out the variables value.

Comment: But if you run the above sample code, it will give you error. What do you want to do actually? You will select a page and that that page will display in the index.php?

Comment: my index page needs to display the content of the page its loaded on. but it must display it where i've inserted the variable

Comment: your question is not clear at all. Can you give some more details or what you want to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents() give you the source of your file.
If I get you right you want to use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) instead. Also don't echo in a variable but assign the value and echo it in the template.

users.php:

```
$content = 'what ever';
include 'template.php';
```

other.php:

```
$content = 'other page';
include 'template.php';
```

template.php:

```
echo $content
```

If you call users.php output will be "what ever". If you call other.php output will be "other page".

Comment: I cant add the contents on the template file then use include because the template file needs to display different content for different pages

Comment: Yes, you say to the template $content for this page ist 'what ever'. On an other page you say ```$content = 'other page'``` and your template displays "other page". The "Page" sets a variable and the template displays it.

Comment: Thank you Mirsch I found my Problem. Your solution worked. The problem was that i was including my functions.php in the template and in the users.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the return value of "echo" in $index_content, which is empty.
Just omit the echo when assigning the string to the variable.

The other problem is, with file_get_contents you don't evaluate the php expression where you echo out the $index_content.

Instead, you should use include('index.php') in users.php, and set the variable $index_contents before that.

Comment: Ok but then how can I display my pages contents through a variable then. I dont want to copy and paste my template code onto every page.

Comment: Please see my last edit - as also @mirsch indicated. Instead of copypasting your template code into every page, you are supposed to use an include and set all required variables before that.